# Which t-test to use for a two-group pre- post-test design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, t-test

I have data on 26 participants (13 from computing and remaining 13 from non computing) who have participated in my research. Each participant is treated with a lab module (Hands on Robotics Session). Now each participant will be evaluated using a rubric on scale of 1 to 4. This experiment has both pre and post test.

For my research i want to evaluate the following questions:

#### Research question 1

- Null Hypothesis: students do not learn about computational thinking (programming basics and algorithmic thinking) with the help of robotics.
- Alternate Hypothesis: Students learn about computational thinking (programming basics and algorithmic thinking) with the help of robotics.

To evaluate the above question, the categories i will be considering are Plan, Implementation and Knowledge gained on a scale of Excellent, Good, Fair and Poor.

I think i should use DEPENDENT T-TEST FOR PAIRED SAMPLES. Am i correct?

#### Research question 2:

- Null Hypothesis: Participants background (computing and non computing) has no effect in learning about algorithmic thinking with help of robotics
- Alternate Hypothesis:Participants background (computing and non computing) has an effect in learning about algorithmic thinking with help of robotics

I will also evaluate question 2 on a scale of Excellent, Good, Fair and Poor, but with respect to background.

#### My Statistical Question

**Which T test should I use for each of my research questions?**

Comment: This question is clearly related to [Statistical analysis for rubric-based research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30490/930),  although it asks for a different test statistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are interested in measuring an increase pre- and post-test, it seems to me that you should use a paired test.

An issue here is that your variables are likely non Gaussian since they are among 4 categories. If your sample size is big (**very** roughly larger than 50), then it is no big deal. Otherwise, I would use the [Wilcoxon signed rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) which is a non parametric analog of the paired t-test.

Comment: **very** roughly is right. What if $P( {\rm category \ 1} ) = 1 - 10^{-200}?$ ;)

Comment: Aha (+1), then I am f... But how likely is that? Close to $10^{-200}$ I'd say :-)

Comment: It's also worth noting that this would also require an assumption that the categories comprise an interval scale. It also seems (unless I misread) that, in question 1, the role of the null and alternative are reversed from the way they normally are in a paired $t$-test; the null appears to be that the module **does** help. Finally, question 2 appears to require a two independent samples test, where the paired differences are the outcome variables.

Comment: I do not subscribe to using the Wilcoxon signed rank test alternative. If you do a simulation study, you can still show the power of the t-test is good --comprable to the signed rank test-- in moderately skewed distributions. If the researchers are interested in testing for a geometric difference in responses, then a log transformation would be justified.

Comment: @marco: Thanks for pointing out that my formation for null and alternate was wrong and thanks for your suggestion on the second question.

Comment: A big +1 for gui11aume for that answer!

Answer (score 1):

gui11aume beat me to it.  He said exactly what I had in mind when I read the question.  Since scaled measurements are not going to fit a normal error distribution very well a nonparametric paired test is the best way to go in my view and for that I would have recommended the Wilcoxon signed rank test.  On the other hand if you were comparing scores by domains where many responses are summed, normality is not a bad assumption and the t test is fairly robust anyway.  So in that situation a paired t test might be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problems with the nature and elaboration of your alternative hipotesis. Your investigation/reserach hypotesis (and all the theoretical model associated with it) is your alternative hipothesis.
Since the variable is clearly ordinal, i´d prefer a Wilcoxon rank test. But anyway i suggest to work out a little bit more your hipothesis.